# How to Create Backups of .sqlitedb and .db files(call,sms,notes,emails,calender) programmatically in objective-C xcode?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios5, xcode4

As all Db files of Calls, SMS, Emails and Calender etc are present in,

```
SMS:         /Var/Mobile/Library/SMS

Contacts /User/Library/AddressBook

Mail:         /Var/Mobile/Library/Mail

Calendar:     /Var/Mobile/Library/Calendar

Call History:     /Var/Mobile/Library/CallHistory

Notes:         /Var/Mobile/Library/Notes

Safari:         /Var/Mobile/Library/Safari
```

how to create backup files of above all programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this if you want to backup that database to your device. apple may not allow you to access the db files of call lists.

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"YOUR DB FILE PATH"]) 
    {
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:"YOUR DB FILE PATH" toPath:@"PATH WHERE YOU WANT TO BACKUP" error:nil]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Backuped");
        } 
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in backuping the database");
        }
    }
```